# Automatically detect loops with potential performance problems in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, performance-testing, sonarqube

Consider the following java code:

```
for (Entity entity : entities) {
  if(entity.getSubEntity().getField() == pField) {
  return entity.getAnotherField();
  }
}
```

This code can cause a performance problem in production environments if `entities` contains a lot of entries. Testing might not find the problem if it is only tested with small lists.

I am aware of the possibilities of writing dynamic tests for the problem, but I am looking for a way of statically analysing and finding potential instances of this problem without manually looking at every for-loop in the code base.

My question is, how can I automatically detect other instances of this problem in my large code base?

Is there a mechanism in eclipse, built-in or plugin?

Is there a rule in sonarqube for this problem? Would it be possible to write a custom rule?

Comment: Not testing with largest and smallest permitted input is comparable to not testing some major flow in the program. If there is no hard upper size limit, test with input comparable to the largest you currently expect, and periodically review to see if you need to make it bigger. You may hit functional bugs, as well as performance issues.

Comment: In general `for`s are smelly there, and common practice in JPA and alike is to specify a central `findThatByPField` query. Living the best practices, and peer reviews might help. And not to forget creating artifical test data. An appropiate integration/unit test would do. Develop by unit test.

Comment: I think having a unit-test for the case is a good idea. I am also looking for a static analysis, because I want to identify existing problems in the code base that is currently not under developement anymore.

Answer (score 3):

There no automated tool to find "problems" like this one since it's not a problem: From the thousands of loops in your code, only one or two might eventually cause problems, depending on the data that your process.

So you need to run the code, listen for feedback and run a profiler on the code when you have identified a bottle neck. Manually.

Comment: Your answer made me think: What if I had a static analyzer, a list of Entitites that might possibly cause the performance problem if accessed in a loop and a custom rule finding every loop in my code base that contains an Entity...

Comment: Static analyzers don't look at data structures, so they don't care what the list contains. Also, the loop above is always a problem if the number of elements is in the millions. The problem is always to find the two loops in your code where the number of elements will eventually be in the millions. No static code analyzer can predict the future.

Comment: Or to put it differently: When you do weather simulations, each data set will take 1-2 hours to process. Which is good enough. For UI code, the same would be absolutely unacceptable.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. While we cannot predict every possible future I still think there is a possible solution, a heuristic at least, that helps me seperating the problematic for-loops from the uncritical ones.

Comment: Have a look to [Modisco](https://wiki.eclipse.org/MoDisco) It contains tools to write queries (think SQL) against Java source code. With that, you should be able to say "find all loops that iterate over `Entity`".